# Not able to get csrf token with spring security 3.2.7

Tags: rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring Security 3.2.7 with spring boot 1.2.3. I am building Rest application and implementing spring security with java config in which CSRF is on by default and I know I can disable it in my overridden configure method with "http.csrf().disable()". But suppose I don't want to disable it, but I need the CSRF token. When i hit the url

`localhost:8080/myproject/url`

with POST request it gives

```
{
    "timestamp": 1431682924618,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?",
    "path": "/myproject/user"
}
```

So how can i hit the same url with successful result without disabling the csrf.

My SecurityConfig file is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // In memory authentication
        /*auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");*/
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }


    @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//      http.csrf().disable()               //Disable csrf security
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/myproject/user/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/myproject/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic();

      }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest a read of the Spring Security [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax). Which explains what to do with ajax/json based applications and how to send the token.